# How to filter or delete the data in object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm very new at javascript.I'm so sorry for asking a very simple question. How can I filter or delete the object that don't meet the criteria in object array.
If I have the object array. Here is my data.

```
 Object = [A,B,C,D,E];

  A = { data: [[0,1], 
              [0,1],  
              [0,2],
              [0,4],
               . 
               .
               .
              [0,6]],
        name: "A",
        Type: "1992"},

 B:  { data: [[1,1],
             [1,3],
             [0,4],
             [4,5],
               .
               .
               .
             [10,16]]
       name: "B",
       Type: "1996"},


  C: { data: [1,3],
             [1,5],
             [0,3],
             [0,6],
              .
              .
              .
             [12,3]],
       name: "C",
       Type: "1985"},


  D : {data: [[1,3],
              [M,6],
              [3,4],
              [0,6],
                .
                .
                ]}
```

I want my out put to be [B,C,E]

All of my Object in the array have data like this. Could you give me the suggestions on how can I delete or filter the object that have the "all" first value in the data equal to 0 or it's not numeric. For example, I want to delete "A" and "D" out of my Object Array because the the first value in "data" array in A contains [0,1],[0,1],[0,2],[0,4] and the first data in "D" contains "m" which is not the number. I would be very grateful if you could help me with this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm a little confused. `B` and `C` also have data elements with `0` in their first index. Should it only filter elements out if *all* of their first indexes are `0`?

Comment: I'm sorry. I need to delete all of their first indexes are 0 @AlexisKing

Comment: Could you provide what you want the output data to look like?

Comment: I want the out put look like this
[B,C,E] just delete A and D.
The code I wrote it just the example, Actually my array have 7000 data. 
and I want to delete the object that contains 0 in all their first data. @AlexisKing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the aptly-named [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
yourData.filter(function (e) { return e.data[0][0] !== 0; });
```

This will return a *new* array containing only the elements matched by the condition.

Comment: I want to completely delete A and D out of my array. Is it possible to do that? @Alexis King